# Correct layout for Bootstrap label in navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add an alert for unread messages in my Bootstrap navbar. I was able to figure out how to format this alert nicely. However, I have not been able to figure out how to format it correctly within an `<a>` tag.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li><a href="/Client/Details">Profile</a></li>
     <li><a href="/Message">Message Trainer</a></li>
     <li>
         <a href="#">
             <span class="navbar-text label label-danger" style="color: white">
                 1
             </span>
         </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This layout looks like this.

[image]

I also tried moving the CSS classes currently in my `<span>` element to the `<a>` element (and remove the span), but that was much worse.

Is there an existing way for Bootstrap to support this, or do I need to just custom style this all?

Comment: I think you have to style it, remove margin from label and see if that helps.

Comment: @makshh: I can style it. But Bootstrap does a lot of stuff. Just wondered if someone knew if this was supported directly.

Comment: Nothing in the docs about that, so probably it's not supported out of the box, but - what's wrong with your code when you remove navbar-text class?

Comment: @makshh: Actually, it's a big improvement? :-) I added that because it was needed to format correctly with just `<span>`. But perhaps with a link, I don't need it. Need to play with it some more.

Comment: You can also hack it a little bit: wrap `<a>` in div so styles from Bootstrap will not apply to your anchor anymore, but then you have to use `navbar-text` on your label to have proper margins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the CSS class: `.navbar-text`;

Result:

```
<span class="label label-danger" style="color: white">
  1
</span>
```

View on JsBin : https://jsbin.com/bugakey/edit?output

```js
alert("View the example on a large screen so that the <nav> elements are displayed inline")
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li><a href="/Client/Details">Profile</a></li>
     <li><a href="/Message">Message Trainer</a></li>
     <li>
         <a href="#">
             <span class="label label-danger " style="color: white">
                 1
             </span>
         </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```